# WPF File Association Issues

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installshield

I have an app that I want to create file associations for.  It's a WPF application and I have an installer built with InstallShield 2012 LE in Visual Studio 2012.

I have added associations via the "File Extensions" screen in the Install Shield project but it doesn't seem to be working for known file types.  If I add a random extension then right click->"open with" on a matching file then the application appears in the list but for known file types it is not present.

Looking at the Registry it seems that the regkey needs to be placed in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER->SOFTWARE->CLASSES->".FILEEXTENSION"->OpenWithProgids`.

Install shield does create the correct `ProgID` entry for the application in the registry but there doesn't seem to be anywhere to tell it to create the missing key with the exception of manually adding it to the registry.

Before MS dropped their own install project out of VS you used to be able to select extensions and the required Verbs.

Am I just missing the correct place to set this up or do I need to manually add the Registry Keys as required?